Vector search to get a uniqueness score based on context
I have a single blog post with a title and description, and I want to compare its uniqueness against multiple blog entries in a CSV file. The CSV contains several blogs, each with a title and meta description.
I am currently using TF-IDF vectorization and cosine similarity to compare the single blog with all the entries in the CSV file. However, this approach only matches based on the exact words and not the context.

What is your question?

I recommend first generating embeddings using the pre-trained model 'paraphrase-MiniLM-L6-v2' from the "sentence_transformers" library. These embeddings should then be stored in a Faiss index, which is a similarity search library developed by Facebook. Once this is set up, you can input new blog titles or other metadata into the Faiss index, and it will return the most similar blogs based on the embeddings.
Additionally, you can control the number of similar blogs returned by the Faiss index, specifying whether you want 5, 7, 10, or any other number of results. You can also set a similarity threshold so that only blogs meeting a certain level of similarity are returned.
